# How to pass ip-address from terraform to ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform

I found several articles and answers on the internet how to pass outputs from terraform to ansible, but i still can't pass ip-address of ec2 from terraform to ansible. For example (look below), Should i declare var.ip in variables.tf file? terraform doesn't accept var.ip without declaration. How to declare this variable if it is terraform output?

```
resource "local_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file_new" {
  content = <<-DOC
    tf_ip: ${var.ip}
    DOC
  filename = "./tf_ansible_vars_file.yml"
}
```

Comment: While your question, or actually the _problem you're having_, is super vague, be aware that yaml is a strict superset of JSON, so just write out a JSON file without trying to manufacture yaml (or, if you insist, use [`yamlencode()`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/yamlencode))

Comment: Can you add the code for EC2 instance to the question above?

Comment: I found another solution how to do it. I used 1 provisioner local-exec, i created the 2nd provisioner, that creates a file with ip address, then my 2nd provisioner launches ansible cmd that uses a file with ip.